# Get name of defining val

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I would like to catch the name of variable that output of my macro is assigned to. Exactly like `project` in build.sbt. I would prefer out of the box solution(library) if there is one, because it looks like pretty general use case.

Here is small example

```
val someValue = myMacro()
```

and as an output of `myMacro()` I would like to get string `"someValue"`.

Comment: the question is not very clear. maybe an example would help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [SourceCode](https://github.com/lihaoyi/sourcecode).

Example:

```
scala> def myName(implicit name: sourcecode.Name) = name.value
myName: (implicit name: sourcecode.Name)String

scala> val foo = myName
foo: String = foo
```

Comment: Exactyl! Thanks a lot.