# Getting variable name while make a new object

Tags: scala

I'm creating an instance from object `Node` for instance. My question is that how can I have a function inside my class that returns the object name for me. For instance, something like this:

```
class Node (val in: Int) {
  def getName() = ...
}
```

And then:

```
val testNode1 = new Node(5)
val testNode2 = new Node(4)

testNode1.getName()    //Print: "testNode1"
testNode2.getName()    //Print: "testNode2"
```

Comment: This sounds like what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160751/get-name-of-defining-val

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get name of defining val](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160751/get-name-of-defining-val)

Comment: @Dylan not really... `new Node(...)` doesn't look like a macro invocation. I'm not sure whether OP really wants some advanced macro tricks at all, I somehow suspect that it's all an XY-problem...

Comment: thanks @Dylan, sourcecode is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: yw Moriss but credit goes to @Tanjin - I just put his link in the close vote but it comes up as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make it work with constructors, but using an auxiliary `def` macro works:

---- build.sbt ----

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies +=
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value % "provided"
```

---- module 1 (e.g. main sources) ----

---- Node.scala ----

```
package foo

class Node (val in: Int, val name: String)
```

---- Macros.scala ----

```
package foo

import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Macros {
  def newNode(c: blackbox.Context)(in: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Node] = {
    import c.universe._
    val owner = c.internal.enclosingOwner
    val name = if (owner.isTerm && owner.asTerm.isVal) {
      owner.name.toString
    } else {
      "unknown"
    }
    val nameExpr = c.Expr(Literal(Constant(name)))
    reify[Node] {
      new Node(in.splice, nameExpr.splice)
    }
  }
}
```

---- module 2 (e.g. test sources) ----

---- Test.scala ----

```
package foo

import scala.language.experimental.macros

object Test {
  def Node(in: Int): Node = macro Macros.newNode

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val bar = Node(1234)
    println(s"The node's name is ${bar.name}")
  }
}
```